# Validator miss a p tag but it's there!

Tags: html, validation

I have the following markup:

```
<footer>
    <p id="foo">
        &copy;Copyright. <address><a href="" title="Web Development">Me</a></address>. Todos os direitos reservados.
    </p>
</footer>
```

But W3 Validator (HTML 5) says:

```
Error Line 81, Column 20: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

                </p>
```

I do have a p tag. What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Does it work properly on your site?

Comment: @thomas I don't know about HTML5 nesting rules, but in HTML 4, a P element cannot contain an ADDRESS element. P elements can only contain inline content, and ADDRESS is a block-level element. http://vidasp.net/HTML-structure-diagram.html

Comment: Blam, It doesn't work because Css render it wrong...

Comment: Šime Vidas, You are right. But what should I do to add my address in copyright? I want to do a semantic work. Thank you guys.

Comment: Change the p into a div, what you are after is a div anyway. The p tag supports ONLY inline elements like pieces of text, span and a etc. and is therefore (by design) limited. If you want an address element then use a div, which gives more freedom. :)

Comment: @thomas You could replace the P element with a DIV element - since the latter allows block content.

Answer (score 14):

> Problem: `<p>` cannot contain an `<address>` *block*

You can nest a `<p>` inside an `<address>`! An `<address>` block just means that there's address information to be found within it. It does not need to be wrapped tightly around the address itself.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-address-element

Comment: Is it right?
"<address id="copyright"><p>&copy;Copyright. <a href="" title="Web Development">Me</a>. Todos os direitos reservados.</p></address>"
It was validated but is it semantic? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed the problem for me to. I was using a <pre> inside of a <p>

Answer (score 2):

**The Layout-Problem:**

why use a wrapper like 'p or 'div for the layout coding anyway? as a block-level element you can use 'adress directly as your container-box and format it with any css as you like. keep code minimal and simple.

**The Semantic-Problem:**

also you dont need a wrapping 'p for the semantics, as 'adress explains its contents already very well. just use it ;-)

**The Syntax-Problem:**

and yes, other answers are right: 
'p contains legally only inline-/inline-block-elements, no block-level-elements allowed

Answer (score -4):

This might be because of you are using HTML5 tags(which is not yet completed by W3c). So simply use divs in order to maintain cross browsing issues.